# SMTP mail error in CodeIgniter : server might not be configured to send mail

Tags: php, codeigniter, email, smtp

I am trying to send SMTP email using CodeIgniter, but I'm getting error in response ...

"**The following SMTP error was encountered: 0
Unable to send email using PHP SMTP. Your server might not be configured to send mail using this method.**"

```
User-Agent: CodeIgniter
Date: Tue, 13 Dec 2016 07:06:56 +0000
From: "Blabla" <xxxxxxxxxxxxxx>
Return-Path: <xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx>
To: xxxxxxxxxxxx
Reply-To: "Explendid Videos" <xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx>
Subject: =?utf-8?Q?=54=68=69=73=20=69=73=20=61=6E=20=65=6D=61=69=6C=20=74=65=73=74?=
X-Sender: bttvsupport@cloudlink.co.in
X-Mailer: CodeIgniter
X-Priority: 3 (Normal)
Message-ID: <584f9e1023f2f@xxx.co.in>
Mime-Version: 1.0


Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary="B_ALT_584f9e1023f99"

This is a multi-part message in MIME format.
Your email application may not support this format.

--B_ALT_584f9e1023f99
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit

It is working. Great!


--B_ALT_584f9e1023f99
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable

It is working. Great!

--B_ALT_584f9e1023f99--
```

Code is

```
$ci = get_instance();
        $ci->load->library('email');
        $config = array();
        $config['protocol'] = "smtp";
        $config['smtp_host'] = "xxxxx";
        $config['smtp_port'] = 25;
        $config['smtp_user'] = "xxxxx"; 
        $config['smtp_pass'] = "xxxxx";
        $config['charset'] = "utf-8";
        $config['mailtype'] = "html";
        $config['newline'] = "\r\n";

        $ci->email->initialize($config);

        $ci->email->from('xxxxx', 'Blabla');
        $list = array('xxxxx');
        $ci->email->to($list);
        $this->email->reply_to('xxxxx', 'Explendid Videos');
        $ci->email->subject('This is an email test');
        $ci->email->message('It is working. Great!');
        if($ci->email->send()){echo "send";}else{echo "error ";print_r($ci->email->print_debugger());}
```

---

Comment: use `$this->ci` instead of `$ci`.

Comment: I would put this $this->ci = get_instance(); in the __construct() area of library

Comment: You need to check with your service provider for your smtp details of server. Also, if you are using gmail to send email from your application then you need to activate the smtp emails from gmail-settings. One thing again, if you uploaded your application on your server, then no need to use ```smtp``` protocol, use ```sendmail``` instead.

Comment: Have you loaded the Email library? And use $this->email->initialize($config);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to load the email library in constructor like

**$this->load->helper(array('email'));
$this->load->library(array('email'));**

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');
class Dispatch extends MY_Controller 
{

        function __construct() {
                        parent::__construct();
                        $this->load->helper('url');
                        $this->load->helper(array('form', 'url'));
                        $this->load->library('form_validation');
                        $this->load->library('session');
                        $this->load->helper(array('email'));
                        $this->load->library(array('email'));

        }

public function sendEmail()
    {
$config = array(
    'protocol'  => 'smtp',
    'smtp_host' => 'smtp.googlemail.com',
    'smtp_port' => '587',
    'smtp_user' => 'test@gmail.com',
    'smtp_pass' => 'XXXXXXX',
    'mailtype'  => 'html', 
    'charset'   => 'iso-8859-1'
);
$this->load->library('email', $config);
$this->email->set_newline("\r\n");
$this->email->set_mailtype("html");
$message2 = '
    <html>
        <head>
            <title>Dispatch</title>
        </head>
        <body>






        Test Mail




        </body>
    </html>
    ';
         $subject="Test Email";
         $message=$message2;
          $this->email->from('test@gmail.com');
          $this->email->to($test@gmail.com);
          $this->email->subject($subject);
          $this->email->message($message);
          if($this->email->send())
         {
                 echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('Email Send Success');</script>";
                 redirect('/Dispatch/', 'refresh');
         }
         else
        {
         show_error($this->email->print_debugger());
        }

    }

}

?>
```

I am also facing same problem but when I try to load library in constructor the email send success.this is work for me hope this will help you too.

Answer (score 0):

```
public function send_mails(){

    $config['useragent'] = 'CodeIgniter';
    $config['protocol'] = 'https';
    $config['smtp_host'] = 'smtp.gmail.com';
    $config['smtp_port'] = '587';
    $config['smtp_user'] = 'youremail@gmail.com';
    $config['smtp_pass'] = '*********';
    $config['wrapchars'] = 76;
    $config['mailtype'] = 'html';
    $config['charset'] = 'iso-8859-1';
    
    $this->load->library('email', $config);

    $from_email = "youremail@gmail.com";
    $to_email = "reseiver@gmail.com";
    //Load email library
    $this->load->library('email');
    $this->email->initialize($config);
    //$this->load->library('email', $config);
    $this->email->from($from_email, 'Identification');
    $this->email->to($to_email);
    $this->email->subject('Send Email Codeigniter');
    $this->email->message('The email send using codeigniter library');
    //Send mail
    if($this->email->send())
       echo "mail sent";
    else
      show_error($this->email->print_debugger());
    

}
```